# Where are files saved in MVC4 2010 project where no path is declared?

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a file with the filepath of simply "test.txt" using File.Create method.

I've managed to email this file to myself using an email class and the filepath of "test.txt".

I want to find the actual file in my project folder, but can't see to find it even with a search for test.txt.

Is it a temp file, and where would it be saved to?

I'm creating the file with the following code:

```
public void createCSVFile()
{
    string fileLocation = "test";
    mFilePath = fileLocation+".txt";

    if (!File.Exists(mFilePath))
    File.Create(mFilePath).Close();
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, especially how you are creating the file?

Comment: put more effort into formatting your code if you need help !

Comment: do you want to save the file to a specific location or do you only want to know where the file is saved ?

Comment: I just want to know where the default save location is. The actual location doesn't matter as I will email the document out.

Comment: i did a small app and used your code, the file is saved relative to the IIS run folder so in my case it's : `C:Program files(x86)\IIS Express`.
You could try and map the file to a specific location, this would be more helpfull for you for debugging.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I will have to set a better location then - better off in the project folder :). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will help you with mapping your files in a specific location to help you further:

**Server.MapPath** specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.

```
Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath(null), Server.MapPath("") will return the physical directory of the file being executed
Server.MapPath("..") will return the parent directory
Server.MapPath("~") will return the physical path to the root of the application
```

To give you an example if you have a website that is stored on disk at C:\Website the mapPath will return the following :

**Server.MapPath("..")** will return : "C:\Website"

**Server.Mappath(".")** will return "C:\Website{controllerName}"

**Server.MapPath("~")** will return : "C:\Website"